# Is it possible to temporary stop sending messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using Rabbit for notifications like slack, mail etc. And my goal is temporary stop receiving messages from Rabbit so that I will not receive messages after working time.

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have from RabbitMQ is to force-close the application's connection. This isn't ideal, so you need to build in a "stop consuming" feature into your application(s).